# how to "dynamically" redirect a http-request to a folder outside the document-root

Tags: lighttpd, symlink

I built a small custom CMS for a couple of clients in PHP on a lighttpd-server. Right now every client has an own copy of the CMS in the user-root:

```
Client1/www/index.php
Client1/www/CMS/includes
Client1/www/CMS/scripts
Client2/www...
```

For better maintenance I decided to put the CMS into an extra folder outside the user-root. So I don't have to update every single client when I develop the CMS:

```
CMS/includes
CMS/scripts
Client1/www/index.php
Client2/www...
```

To redirect a http-request like ***www.client1.com/scripts/default.js*** I simply put a symlink in the user-root:

```
CMS/scripts -> ../../CMS/scripts
```

So far, so good. But now the project is getting bigger and I need to use different versions of "CMS":

```
CMS_1.0/...
CMS_1.2/...
```

With simple PHP-includes this is no problem. I just declare the version as a GLOBAL in a little config-script inside Client1/www/ and include like:

```
include "../../CMS_".$GLOBALS["version"]."/includes/myClass.php";
```

But for all the http-requests (CSS, JS and Ajax-loaded PHP) I would need to write new symlinks every time I change to a new version of "CMS"

```
CMS/scripts -> ../../CMS_1.0/scripts
```

#### Question:

Is there any way I can redirect ***www.client1.com/scripts/default.js*** to ***../../CMS_1.0/scripts*** using a variable like $version in the symlink or by configuring lighttpd or any other way?

I hope you guys understand my problem...

Comment: Are you using PHP? Include the relevant tag, if such is a case.

Comment: I think you're using PHP and retaged accordingly. Remove it, if such is not a case.

Comment: Well, I use PHP for my CMS. But the question is rather about the request-handling of lighttpd... May the tag help me out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Either symlink the directory instead of single files or use lighttpd's mod_alias for your scripts directory: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModAlias